# Disappearing Icons on Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, home-screen

On my Samsung Galaxy S2, sometimes all of the icons will disappear from the home screens except for the 4 built in icons (phone, messaging, web, applications). This sometimes happens at startup, and sometimes happens after the phone has been running for a while. It can only be fixed by rebooting the phone, although that is not a guaranteed fix.

More recently I've encountered an additional problem: Sometimes when the icons disappear, the Applications button stops bringing up my applications menu.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: It's a critical problem.. Backup your data and hard reset your device.

Comment: define "critical problem"?

Comment: Sounds to me like the launcher app is having a problem. What happens if you clear data for the launcher app? Or install a 3rd party launcher?

Comment: I guess I should update this: Eventually, a more serious problem started occurring where my phone wouldn't turn on. I took it to a service center, it was diagnosed as a hardware defect and they gave me a replacement phone.

Comment: I keep having this problem on multiple devices, all the way to Android 12. It's not a hardware problem for sure. In fact it may be just a symptom of multiple different underlying problems, but my current best guess is that the fault is with the specific launcher app, and replacing it with a 3rd party app should help. The default launcher app seems to often be heavily customized by the vendor, which goes toward explaining how the bug is propagated into each new android version.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought based on what I experienced.
I saw icons disappearing on an Android tablet, when I move the apps to SD card or apps installed on SD card instead of internal default flash memory. Are these apps installed on an external SD card? if the SD card is not initialized when the home screen becomes active, they may not be available.

Comment: I do have an SD card, but I don't think any apps are installed there.